# PHP Extension: call_user_function from a pthread returns error

Tags: php, pthreads, php-extension

I am currently working on a PHP extension. This PHP extension should also make use of multithreading via pthreads. Inside the thread a function in PHP userspace should be called via `call_user_function`. PHP is configured with the `--enable-maintainer-zts` config option.

I already have written some code that calls a PHP function in user space that works as expected. See the following code snippets for a minimal working example:

**Extension Code (in C)**

```
PHP_FUNCTION(hello_world)
{
    startWorker();
    RETURN_NULL();
}

void *startWorker() {

    static zval retval;

    zval function_name;
    INIT_ZVAL(function_name);
    ZVAL_STRING(&function_name, "hello", 1);

    TSRMLS_FETCH();

    if (call_user_function(CG(function_table), NULL, &function_name, &retval, 0, NULL TSRMLS_CC) == SUCCESS) {
        printf("successfully called function\n");
    } else {
        printf("calling user function returned an error\n");
    }

    zval_dtor(&function_name);
}
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php

function hello() {
        echo "php hello() called\n";
}
hello_world();
```

If I call the PHP code, it returns the following output - just as expected.

```
php hello() called
successfully called function
```

But now I want to call the PHP function from a new thread. So I modify the extension code as follows:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(hello_world)
{
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create( &thread, NULL, &startWorker, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
    RETURN_NULL();
}
```

But now, all of a sudden, calling the PHP code results in following output:

```
calling user function returned an error
```

I could track down the source of the error to the following if statement in the [zend_call_function](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_execute_API.c#L733), however I have no idea why `EG(active)` is false at this point an how I can prevent this:

```
if (!EG(active)) {
    return FAILURE; /* executor is already inactive */
}
```

So my questions are:

- Is it even possible to call PHP userspace functions inside threads?
- If so, why does `call_user_function` return an error?
- What does EG(active) mean? How can I make it evaluate to true inside a pthread?

Any hints on this are highly appreciated.

Comment: http://php.net/Thread

Comment: @JoeWatkins I'm not really sure what you are trying to point out with that comment :) Just to avoid confusion, this question is not about the PHP pthreads extension, but a custom extension that uses the POSIX pthread library for C

Comment: Seemed like a good starting place whatever the goal. Whether you use pthreads or just start your research there. The topic is long and complicated, nor could or should it be done justice here (SO posts live forever). In short, as you have seen: no, it is not ordinarily possible (in zts mode) or a good idea (in any mode) to execute what is compiled in another context, the resulting behaviour will vary in strangeness but never be the desired result.

Comment: @moeso do you know how much you can achieve by looking at those source codes ???